# Wordpress Author Information show paragraph?

Tags: author, user-meta

In back-end I'm update 3 paragraph in Author information.

But it's showing frontend it's collapsed. And not showing paragraph.

How to fix this problem.

Ex:
paragraph 1.

paragraph 2.

paragraph 3.

In front-end showing 
paragraph 1. paragraph 2. paragraph 3.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use wpautop()
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

**Example**

```
<?php
///MUST BE IN A LOOP

echo wpautop(get_the_author());
///MUST BE IN A LOOP
?>
```

So you will need to find out where author name are being displayed in the code.
Normally the default file is author.php

Comment: I'm tried. But it's not working.